# To check if the continuity of dates are missing in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to check in my dataframe's column that if there is a missing date for a certain month then the code should output the following month in the format MMM- YYYY

The data set looks like this :

```
                date_start_balance  date_end_balance    start_balance
                22.02.16            22.03.16             3590838
                22.04.16            22.05.16             69788
                15.06.16            21.07.16             452165
```

Both date cols are in datetime format. Now in the above data set the dates are missing for March and May in the start col and this should be returned as MMM-YYYYY

I have tried the following code :

```
import datetime
dates = df1['date_start_balance'].tolist()
missing = []
for i in range(0,len(dates)-1):
   if dates[i+1].month - dates[i+1].month != 1:
    for j in range(dates[i].month+1,dates[i+1].month):
        missing.append(datetime(dates[i].year, j,1))
print(missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a date range with `pd.date_range`

```
march = pd.date_range(start='2016-05-01', end='2016-05-31')
```

And then you will have the list with the dates that you already have, in the example there is only one date: `2016-05-15`:

```
your_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime('15052016', "%d%m%Y").date()]
```

And then you can calculate the difference between the range and your list and get the dates that you are missing:

```
march.difference(your_list)

DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-01', '2016-05-02', '2016-05-03', '2016-05-04',
               '2016-05-05', '2016-05-06', '2016-05-07', '2016-05-08',
               '2016-05-09', '2016-05-10', '2016-05-11', '2016-05-12',
               '2016-05-13', '2016-05-14', '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17',
               '2016-05-18', '2016-05-19', '2016-05-20', '2016-05-21',
               '2016-05-22', '2016-05-23', '2016-05-24', '2016-05-25',
               '2016-05-26', '2016-05-27', '2016-05-28', '2016-05-29',
               '2016-05-30', '2016-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: but I have a lot of data and I want to use the col name instead of passing hard coded dates. what could be solution in that case?

Comment: If you dont want to hardcode the date range you can pick min and max from your list. If it is the values you already have then you can get unique from the start date column.